# How do I get the selected state of a gtk::RadioButton in Rust?

Tags: rust, radio-button, gtk, gtk-rs

In Python's Gtk module, you can use `Gtk.RadioButton.get_active()` to get whether the radio button is checked or not. However, I can't find any such method in Rust's equivalent, [`gtk::RadioButton`](https://docs.rs/gtk/latest/gtk/struct.RadioButton.html). When I try to use `RadioButton.active()`, I get an error saying that the trait bounds were not satisfied for `gtk::RadioButton`. I've tried searching `get(`, `active`, `checked`, `state`, and `selected` in the docs, to no avail. This should be pretty self-explanatory, so I don't think I need to provide a code example. Does anyone know how to get the selected `RadioButton` in Rust (ideally without using a callback)?

Comment: I think it's `is_active`,

Comment: @JohnKoch Yes, it is, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the one-and-only [official Gtk3 documentation](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtk/gtk3/class.RadioButton.html), you'll see that `RadioButton` does not define an `active` property. Instead it is inherited from its base class [`ToggleButton`](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/gtk/gtk3/method.ToggleButton.get_active.html).

AIUI, in gtk-rs, functions and properties inherited are actually part of the associated interface, not of the type itself. So your property is [`ToggleButtonExt::is_active()`](https://docs.rs/gtk/latest/gtk/prelude/trait.ToggleButtonExt.html#tymethod.is_active).

In theory your `RadioButton` value implements `IsA<ToggleButton>` so it also implements `ToggleButtonExt`, and the `is_active()` method should be readily available.

If it says that the trait is not in scope maybe you forgot the `use gtk::prelude::*;`?

Comment: Of course, I should have though of using `is_active()`. I wonder why it didn't appear in my searches for `active`? Maybe it's because of the multiple levels of inherited traits.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: That search failure happened to me many times. Now I look for what I want in the regular Gtk3 docs, and once I know exactly what I'm looking for, I go to the rust doc page for that type, its *Ext trait and *ExtManual trait, if it exists.